# Ubuntu password reset

Tags: grub2, password

I forgot my Ubuntu password, can't open grub menu either, is there a way to fix this? Help please

I tried to open grub menu after turning on my PC, with ESC, shift nothing worked, also went to etc/default but could not find grub file

Answer (score 0):

Obtain a copy of Ubuntu Install image or Live Image on a usb drive.  Boot from that USB drive.

When the Install screen appears, press ctrl + alt F3, this will give you a shell.  In the shell type, `sudo bash` this will now give you root access.

Find the drive that has your original operating system installed with:

```
lsblk
```

then run:

```
mkdir /mnt/newroot
mount /dev/sdx /mnt/newroot (replace with the correct device you identified)
or if your root is on a lvm
mount /dev/mapper/....... /mnt/newroot (replace with the correct device you identified)
mount -R /run /mnt/newroot/run
mount -R /dev /mnt/newroot/dev
mount -R /proc /mnt/newroot/proc
mount -R /sys /mnt/newroot/sys
chroot /mnt/newroot /bin/bash
```

This will put you into a root shell of your orignal operating system, to change your password of your account, type:

```
passwd <username>
```

enter your new password when prompted.

you will now be able to reboot and log into your system as you normally would have.